# Conditional Formatting to highlight dates past due

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet which indicates when dates listed in Column `N` are coming up within the next 30 days (red, italic text) or are overdue (red, italic text and yellow cell fill).

I have achieved this by conditional formatting based on cell value with the formulas `=NOW()+30` and `=NOW()`.

The problem I am having is that when I enter a date or text into column `O` in the corresponding row, I want the conditional formatting to revert back to no format.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you saying?  That when you enter a value in column `O`, you want the value _in column `N`_ to revert to normal formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the an `IF` statement in the formula to check column `O`.

```
=IF(ISBLANK($O1), [your formula]," ")
```

In essence, this checks if `O` is blank. If so, it runs your formula. If not, it skips it.